# Xamarin.Forms: Static part of DataTemplate

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `CarouselView` where I bind my collection. For each item in `ItemsSource` I display some data related with current item. However by design / UI reasons in each of my item`s view I also add a part of view which I reuse all for all rendered items and is not related with binding.

```
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <!-- Part where I use current item for binding    -->
     
           <!-- Part where I have views which are not related with current item  -->
       </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
```

If I do put second part into current ContentView's resources and use as `StaticResource` by x:Key  will I gain performance?

Comment: For the second part do you want to use this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries)？